# How to change number format in excel sheet through VB.net?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, excel

I have a program to convert `DataGrid` into excel sheet.It is working. But now my problem is if my data is "763040059412" in `Datagrid`,after converting in my excel sheet it is showing as "7.6304E+11". I dont know what to do..Please help me. Thanking you

Comment: This sounds like a excel formatting problem rather than a programming one.

Comment: what do you wanna display and what procedure do you implement to create excel ? interop or openXml ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel automation set NumberFormat of the range as shown below where I am using your value shown. If I were to insert that value w/o setting NumberFormat the result is same as you got but using NumberFormat the number is formatted correctly.

Here I am working with a Excel file in the executable folder, you would adjust to point to your existing or newly created Excel file.

```
Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Formatting.xlsx")
Dim value As Long = 763040059412
OpenExcelDoFormat(FileName, "", "Sheet1", "G2", 763040059412)
```

Backing code where I open the file via process.start to instantly see results. Note the parameter SaveFileName means nothing here as I tweaked another demo I did for another question.

```
Option Strict On
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module OpenWorkSheets4
    Public Sub OpenExcelDoFormat(
        ByVal OpenFileName As String,
        ByVal SaveFileName As String,
        ByVal SheetName As String,
        ByVal CellAddress As String,
        ByVal NewCellValue As Long)

        If IO.File.Exists(OpenFileName) Then

            Dim Proceed As Boolean = False

            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
            Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing

            xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

            xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
            xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(OpenFileName)

            xlApp.Visible = False

            xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets

            For x As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheets.Count
                xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkSheets(x), Excel.Worksheet)
                If xlWorkSheet.Name = SheetName Then
                    Proceed = True
                    Exit For
                End If

                Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
                xlWorkSheet = Nothing

            Next
            If Proceed Then
                xlCells = xlWorkSheet.Range(CellAddress)
                xlCells.Select()

                xlCells.NumberFormat = "0"
                xlCells.Value = NewCellValue.ToString

                Dim xlColumns As Excel.Range = Nothing
                xlColumns = xlCells.EntireColumn
                xlColumns.AutoFit()
                Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlColumns)
                xlColumns = Nothing
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(SheetName & " not found.")
            End If

            xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(OpenFileName)

            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.UserControl = True
            xlApp.Quit()

            ReleaseComObject(xlCells)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks)
            ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
            Process.Start(OpenFileName)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("'" & OpenFileName & "' not located. Try one of the write examples first.")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReleaseComObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            If obj IsNot Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            End If
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Go till the cell or range level and apply `NumerFormat = "#,##0.00"`